# Is polygon operation in CGAL working with polygon that has duplicated edge?

Tags: cgal

I have a polygon as such:

[image]

{0}, {1}, {2}, {3},... denote the sequence of the points on the polygon.

I wonder whether [CGAL polygon boolean set-operations](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Boolean_set_operations_2/index.html) work with polygon as such?

From the [user manual](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Boolean_set_operations_2/index.html#fig__simpleDefsExamples), the input polygon must be simple or relatively simple in order for the CGAL polygon boolean set-operations to work:

> A relatively simple polygon allows vertices with a degree >2, but all
>   of its edges are disjoint in their interior. Furthermore, it must be
>   an orientable polygon. Namely when it is inserted into an arrangement
>   and its outer boundary is traversed, the same face is adjacent to all
>   of the halfedges (no crossing over any curve during the traversal).
>   Note that while polygon C has the same curves as polygon B, traversal
>   of the curves leads to crossing over a previously traversed curve, and
>   is therefore neither simple nor relatively simple.

Not sure what it really means, but my guess is that the polygon is still ( at least) relatively simple, and hence the CGAL polygon boolean operation still works... am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the condition for a valid polygon in the [user manual](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Boolean_set_operations_2/index.html#title2), you'll see that the input polygon must be simple. Yours is not since you have a duplicated edge.

Comment: that's the problem, I am not sure whether the polygon above is simple or relatively simple or not...

Comment: It's not since an edge is duplicated.

Comment: @sloriot Please edit your answer so that it says why the polygon is not simple.